# How to import testcases in TFS from excel sheet

Tags: tfs

I need some help on writing a macro, which will upload the test cases in `Excel` sheet directly into `TFS`.

Comment: Hi Monika, Could you provide some detail around what you are trying to do?  Does the Excel file contain data used to set-up the test cases, or does it actually detail the tests?

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Hi Joerage Thanks for replying back
I have a excel shet which contains test cases.This sheet contains all the columns which are there in TFS for a test case.Now i need to have an upload button on excel sheet and when i click that upload button all test cases get uploaded in TFS automatically.I also have one cell which contains the name of the porject for which i need to uplaod test cases.

Answer (score 3):

Does it have to be a macro?

If not, [Test Case Migrator Plus](http://tcmimport.codeplex.com/) will do what you need:

> Test Case Migrator Plus tool allows test related artifacts, present in
>   Excel and MHT/Word formats, to be imported into Team Foundation
>   Server. It works with both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 11
>   (Beta).

Comment: It should work with 2015 as well, but you'll need to install the correct version of the TFS Client Object Model incl all required hotfixes (2010 or 2012 depending on the version you download). You can find the required fixes on my blog: http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/10/connecting-to-tfs-from-any-version-of.html

Comment: I'm using TFS 2018. Test Case Migrator Plus tool not supported. Any alternatives? Kindly help!

Comment: Hi @venkat, this answer is from 7 years ago so there's a good chance it hasn't been updated to work with newer versions of TFS.  I'd suggest posting it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is very old question but recently i was trying the same and figure out how to upload TC to TFS from Excel. You can use Excel to directly upload Test case to TFS  Refer to link- http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&rd=true&l=EN-US&k=k(vs.tfc.office.excelworkitems)